# How do I return only the id which contains an invalid number in the numberid column?

Tags: sql, select, group-by, firebird

I have a dataset like this

```
id,  numberid  
1,   45  
1,   45  
1,   41  ->invalid number, should be 45  
2,   60  
2,   60  
2,   60  
3,   71  
3,   71  
3,   72  ->invalid number, should be 71
```

Each group of rows (1,2,3) should contain the same code number as well. Group 1 has an invalid number (marked) and group 3 has an invalid number (marked).
How can I return only the group id (like 1 and 3) which contain the invalid numbers?

Comment: Is this a database table or in-memory dataset? What specific technologies (database, programming language etc.) are you using?

Comment: Hi Sergey, it is a Firebird database table, looking for an answer in sql query if possible.

Comment: Let me be one amongst no doubt many modelling pedants to point out that this problem is an artefact of a poor data model.  If the NUMBERID always has a 1:1 relationship with the ID then one of those columns is superfluous and should be normalised away.

Comment: why 1,41 and 3,72 are invalid?

Answer (score 1):

This will show you the groups and the less popular numberids

```
select 
    your_table.id, numberid
from your_table 
    inner join  (select id from your_table group by id having count(distinct numberid) >1) distinctitems 
        on your_table.id = distinctitems.id
    inner join 
        (
            select id, max(numbercount) as occurrencesofmostpopular
            from
            (
                select id, numberid, count(*) as numbercount
                from your_table 
                group by id, numberid
            ) a
            group by id
        ) mostpopular
        on your_table.id = mostpopular.id

group by your_table.id, your_table.numberid, occurrencesofmostpopular
having (count(*)<occurrencesofmostpopular) or (occurrencesofmostpopular=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the trick:

```
SELECT id FROM your_table GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(numberid) > 1;
```

If you want to know what specific value has invlid numberid then you'll need nore complex query and you have to define what "invalid number" is. Is invalid number the one that has the least occurencies for current id?

Comment: Yes Sergey, I will have to re-think what makes it invalid. I have inherited some bad data and am trying to fix it. Thanks. I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
  g.id,
  COUNT(g.id)
FROM
  (SELECT id, numberid FROM your_table GROUP BY 1, 2) g
GROUP BY
  1
HAVING
  COUNT(g.id) > 1
```